# Can't find component from schematics

Tags: identification, components

Very newbie in the field of electronics and starting to learning about it and playing with [EasyEDA](https://easyeda.com). 
I'm copying a schematic and can't find the component I show in the [image: picture] named NM. What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a 2 pin header. It's used so you can program the EEPROM - pulling `WP` low on 24Cxx EEPROMs allows write access. It looks something like this:

[image]

The spacing between the pins is 2.54 mm (0.1"), and you connect the two pins together when you want to write to the EEPROM.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Does it have a standard name? I can't find it in EasyEDA to draw it.

Comment: @Miguel - see Andy's answer below. And no problem!

Answer (score 2):

"NM" is likely to be an abbreviation for "not mounted" i.e. the symbol represents two solder pads in the circuit board that don't have a component fitted. The pin called "WP" on the CAT24C32 stands for "write protect" and without a solder link or header and bridge fitted (that pulls WP down to 0 volts) the chip cannot be written to. It's a form of protection as the name implies: -

[image]

Of course you can solder a two pin header to the PCB solder pads - it's optional but, on the schematic shown in the question, it's likely that there isn't a header fitted.

> *Does it have a standard name? I can't find it in EasyEDA to draw it*

In EasyEDA you are probably looking for something with a name like this:

[Header-Male-2.54_1x2](https://easyeda.com/component/2b8b516dbbff41adb651468612782419)

[image]